# Adding more svg elements to my document at runtime

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an html file, I'm adding am  element to it dynamically, then a rectangle. Works well in the different browsers (ignoring IE). When I try to use the same method to dynamically create an  element, it does not work in Chrome or Safari, only in Opera. Is my syntax wrong, or does webkit probably just not support adding  elements at runtime? (the same  element works fine if I declare it as tags up-front instead). Maybe I'm not supposed to use appendChild() with these types of nodes? Here's what I have, you should be able to dump it into an html file and run it. If anyone has any idea if there's a way around this, it'd be great:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>

    window.onload = function() {
        var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        svg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
        svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1');
        svg.setAttribute('width', '800px');
        svg.setAttribute('height', '400px');
        document.body.appendChild(svg);

        var rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
        rect.setAttribute("id", "myrect"); 
        rect.setAttribute("fill","red");
        rect.setAttribute("stroke","black");
        rect.setAttribute("stroke-width","5");
        rect.setAttribute("x", "100");
        rect.setAttribute("y", "100");
        rect.setAttribute("width", "100");
        rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
        svg.appendChild(rect);

        var anim = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','animate');
        anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "width");
        anim.setAttribute("from", "100");
        anim.setAttribute("to", "400");
        anim.setAttribute("dur", "10s");
        anim.setAttribute("begin", "0s");
        anim.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
        rect.appendChild(anim);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You really should use `setAttributeNS(null, ...)` when using namespace calls like `document.createElementNS()`.

From [xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/faq.html](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/faq.html)

> However, it is important to know that some implementations make a
>   difference between setAttribute(x, y) and setAttributeNS(null, x, y),
>   so it is good practice to use setAttributeNS which is the only
>   guaranteed interoperable way of setting attributes in a namespace
>   aware DOM implementation.

Comment: Kyle, what is the effect of setAttributeNS(null, ...) vs setAttribute()? I'm not sure what it does to the DOM, thanks.

Comment: From: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/faq.html, "However, it is important to know that some implementations make a difference between setAttribute(x, y)  and setAttributeNS(null, x, y), so it is good practice to use setAttributeNS which is the only guaranteed interoperable way of setting attributes in a namespace aware DOM implementation. "

Answer (score 0):

Ughh this looks like a bug in webkit. You have to call node.beginElement() to get the animation to start, but in webkit it doesn't work, appears in the bug tracker.

Blast.

Comment: Please, do you have a link to the exact bug in the WebKit bug tracker? It would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @tillda maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520493/svg-elements-will-not-animate-when-added-dynamically