# How to create an attribute in SVG using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a script in my application that hides g elements in an SVG that have specific ID values, but this only works if the g element has a visibility attribute.  However, the SVGs I'm using do not have a visibility attribute on the g elements and I'm not in control of the source.  Therefore, I need to find a way to dynymically add the visibility attribute when the parent HTML page is loaded.

I would like the script to create the visibility attribute on all g elements that are children of `<g id="Callouts">`.  For instance, the final code would look something like this:

```
<g id="Callouts">
  <g id="Callout1" visibility="visible">...</g>
  <g id="Callout2" visibility="visible">...</g>
</g>
```

I've looked all over for examples where attributes are added to the SVG structure, but haven't been able to find anything yet.  It also doesn't help that I'm a complete novice when it comes to JavaScript.  Does anyone know how to do this?

**UPDATE:** I coupled Digital Plane's suggested code with the code I'm using to access the SVG document.  The resulting function is below.  This is supposed to show every g element under `<g id="Callouts">`.  However, I keep getting an "object not supported" error on the for loop.

```
function displayOnload (svgName) {
    var svgEmbed = document.embeds[svgName];
    if (typeof svgEmbed.getSVGDocument != 'undefined') {
        var svgDocument = svgEmbed.getSVGDocument();
        var parentElement = svgDocument.getElementById('Callouts');
        if (parentElement != null) {
            var childElements = parentElement.getElementsByTagname('g');
            for (var i=0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
                childElements[i].setAttribute('visibility', 'visible');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please forgive my ignorance about JavaScript, but what am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: Here is an example of my HTML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Drop Bar assembly (2328775)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayOnload (svgName) {
      var svgEmbed = document.embeds[svgName];
      if (typeof svgEmbed.getSVGDocument != 'undefined') {
        var svgDocument = svgEmbed.getSVGDocument();
        var parentElement = svgDocument.getElementById('Callouts');
        var childElements = parentElement.getElementsByTagName('g');
        for (var i=0; i &lt; childElements.length; i++) {
          childElements[i].setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
      }
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="displayOnload('SVG')">
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you try using `getElementsByTagName` instead `getElementsByTagname`? Also, what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Thanks for catching that! However, after updating the script, I'm now getting a "Expected ')'" error at the for loop, and an "Object expected" error at `<body onload="displayOnload('SVG')">`.

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML code?

Comment: I posted an example of my HTML code.  Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute), with something like this:

```
element.setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
```

If you want all `g` elements that are children of `<g id="Callouts">`, do this on document load:

```
var element = document.getElementById("Callouts");
var elements = element.getElementsByTagName("g");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  elements[i].setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  It seems like it would work, but I'm running into one small problem.  I've updated the original post to explain.

Answer (score 2):

No, you must use setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible);

setAttribute might not work on/in svg on some browsers.

Or to be more blunt:
setAttribute is [DOM1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttributeNS)
setAttributeNS is [DOM2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttributeNS)
 Svg has name spaces, svg is xml so setAttributeNS is for you.

Comment: setAttribute is essentially equal to setAttributeNS(null, ...) as long as you don't use prefixed attributes, so for most attributes it works just fine with setAttribute.

Comment: It should be equal, but it's not! It's just browser implementation. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156278/adding-more-svg-elements-to-my-document-at-runtime