# SVG elements will not Animate when added dynamically

Tags: html, svg, html5-animation

I have trying to achieve SVG element's animation while adding dynamic DOMs for its animation with jQuery.
I generate DOMs with JS, so HTML page does not have any elements for this animation.
When I add it dynamically, animation will not start in Chrome(16), however it works with FF(8)

The animation would perfect is I remove that dynamic doms which are generated with JS and put them static into HTML page.

I have created fiddle for it at  : http://jsfiddle.net/cjP6K/7/

where I have put one svg dom static into HTML page, then I have cloned that element with jQuery on document ready,
In this scene, the one which was added later with JS will not Animate at all !!(this works with FF)

Please help...

Thanks,
Chetan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a chrome bug in the animateMotion tag, it has been an issue for ages..

refer to the bug report here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13585

There isn't much that can be done to get around it in chrome while still maintaining an svg dom..

Hope this helps..

Comment: to note that, I have found possible another bug of chrome, its like that, If I create SVG (only <svg>) element on fly with JS, it would not animate, infact, there also issue like, If that svg is created on fly with JS on document ready, it would work !!! I have created fiddle for non-working : http://jsfiddle.net/AFaae/1/ , working : http://jsfiddle.net/tap0ri/mBXKA/1/

Comment: I have also had issues dynamically adding svg when using filters! try removing the filters from your css and inline (if you have any) and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I have not used any css in the page