# How to create SVG animation tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have this SVG circle with an animation:

```
 <circle cx="30" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
  <animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 Z" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
```

It works fine. I want to make the exact same thing using JavaScript so if I click a button, it would create the same circle with the same animation.

Here is my try:

```
    var animateMotion = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animateMotion");
    animateMotion.setAttribute("dur", "8s");
    animateMotion.setAttribute("d", "M 0 0 H 300 Z");
    animateMotion.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite");
    // Assuming that I already created my circle
    myCircle.appendChild(animateMotion);
```

Comment: I've got similar problem with Firefox.

Comment: Documentation: [W3C Recommendation SVG 1.1. 2011, sect. "Animation"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe this is your problem:**

In XML:

```
<animateMotion path= ... />
```

In JS:

```
animateMotion.setAttribute("d", ... ); //Should this be "path"?
```

Hope it helps,
regards m93a.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var animateMotion = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','animateMotion');
    animateMotion.setAttribute("dur","3s");
    animateMotion.setAttribute("repeatCount","1");
    var mpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','mpath');
    mpath.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#YourPath");
    animateMotion.appendChild(mpath);
```

Comment: Please explain what changes you made, and how your code fixes the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `animateMotion` elements are bugged in Webkit, when dinamically created (see [SVG elements will not Animate when added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520493/svg-elements-will-not-animate-when-added-dynamically)), and unsupported in IE. I think you're better off using pure javascript animation using a library like [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).

Answer (score 0):

If just the **click** is important, it can be solved by using the `begin` attribute in your `animateMotion`:

```xml
<svg height="500" width="500" id="foo"> 
<circle cx="30" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
  <animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 Z" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="foo.click"/>
</circle>
</svg>
```

Should work with a button as well, if the button has an identifier, e.g. `id="startbutton"`, then it should be `begin="startbutton.click`

Another alternative with inline javascript can be found here: http://svg-whiz.com/svg/PausePlay.svg

cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you want the animate as soon as `<animateMotion>` element append page,
set `<animateMotion>` 'begin' to 'indefinite' and begin the animate call its .beginElement();

```
var animateMotion = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'animateMotion');
animateMotion.setAttribute('begin', 'indefinite');
//append animateMotion to the page
animateMotion.beginElement();
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/) you can get number of examples regarding svg using javascript.

You can get help from there.